# Power BI PRO license is required for another users?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I  have a huge doubt about power bi pro, at the moment I have  the license for my own, however I have created  a dashboard that I want to share with my team,  do they also need a Power BI license pro to see the dashboard?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Power BI Service, to share reports and dashboards, the other users in the workspace will need a Pro license to consume it. The Microsoft docs site outlines this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-features-license-type

However since you have tagged Power BI Report Server, which is a self hosted/on premise cut down version of Power BI, to share reports in that application you will not need Pro licenses to share items. You only need Pro to deploy to Report Server, but that is reports only, you don't get dashboards in that app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/get-started

Comment: first of all, I am sorry for my late answer, thank you so much for this, I have read all the information.

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it helped you